# How do I run PHP code when a user clicks on a link in reference to id database?

Tags: php

Please help

```
<?php
$sql= "SELECT * FROM servicecredit WHERE studid='$studid'";

$records=mysql_query($sql); ?>
<?php while ($data=mysql_fetch_array($records)){  ?>

<a href='serviceOutput.php?id='<?php echo($data['studid'])?> > Service Credit </a>
```

the output should display in address bar
"http://localhost:8080/bacoor/login/serviceOutput.php?id=1"

the id=1 but always like this "http://localhost:8080/bacoor/login/serviceOutput.php?id="

no id number displayed in the address bar...

Comment: I think `$studid` must be `$studid= $_POST['id']; `

Comment: when i changed to POST it says undefined index

Comment: Where is your $studid defined? Try adding $studid= $_POST['studid']; before your query.  If you're getting undefined index the cause is probably you're not really POSTing this and $studid is empty thus the sql does not work.

Answer (score 1):

think there is any **interrupt with method** of receiving data

use

```
$studid= $_REQUEST['id'];
```

> Note: Make sure there is value in `studid` same to your assing data(`$studid`)

Comment: how can i get data from my database in studid to display the number <?php echo($data['studid'])?>

Comment: Is there any data associate with your `id` ??

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href='serviceOutput.php?id=<?php echo($data['studid']);?>'> Service Credit </a>
```

**TRY THIs this may work**

Comment: Did you tried this this will work your above portion which i answered is wrong this works

Answer (score 0):

try using mysql_fetch_assoc($records)
and try using this
" > Service Credit